# golang exec find command regex

Tags: regex, shell, go, find

I am trying to write a `find` command (shell command below) in go:

```
find . -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -regex '.*\(type-a\|type-b\)\/os.*'
```

Here is the go snippet:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {

    cmd := exec.Command("/usr/bin/find", "/opt/system/versions",
                        "-mindepth",  "3", "-maxdepth",  "3",
                        "-regex",  ".*(type-a|type-b)/os.*")

    var out bytes.Buffer
    var stderr bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &out
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr

    err:= cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(err) + ": " + stderr.String())
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Directory contents : ", out.String())
}
```

It works fine if I search for just `type-a` (or just `type-b`). Does not work when I search for either `type-a` or `type-b` (the shell command works just fine). What did I get wrong in the regex pattern fed into `Command`?

When I escape the `(`, `|` and `)` using `\` , go complains about the escape sequence - `unknown escape sequence: (`:

```
    cmd := exec.Command("/usr/bin/find", "/opt/system/versions",
                        "-mindepth",  "3", "-maxdepth",  "3",
                        "-regex",  ".*\(type-a\|type-b\)/os.*")
```

Comment: You should escape `(`, `|`, and `)` in the Go script as well

Comment: I believe the `|` is interpreted as a shell `pipe` for `find` command.

Comment: @bulbus it is not interpreted as shell pipe, shell does not process the parameters at all when using `exec.Command`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `find` interprets regular expressions as [*Emacs Regular Expressions*](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/emacs-regular-expression-syntax.html), where, particularly, the alteration operator is `\|`, and grouping is performed with backslashes followed by parentheses `\(`, `\)`. So you should either use the correct Emacs Regular Expressions syntax, or use alternative regular expressions syntax with the help of `-regextype` option, where these operators are not prefixed with backslashes, e.g.:

```
find -regextype 'posix-extended' -regex '.*(type-a|type-b)/os.*'
```

Since backslash in Go is used as an escape character in strings, you should escape the backslash character itself with an extra backslash, e.g.:

```
cmd := exec.Command("/usr/bin/find", "/opt/system/versions",
                    "-mindepth",  "3", "-maxdepth",  "3",
                    "-regex",  ".*\\(type-a\\|type-b\\)\\/os.*")
```

Comment: This is not working with pgrep Linux command when '|' is used inside the pattern expression. Looks like a bug in Golang.